# Wrong Upvote shown?

Tags: discussion, reputation, up-votes

I recently visited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682919/removing-url-fragment-from-nsurl) which has [this answer - deleted only seen by users who has reputation more than 10k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8727899/696134)

[image: Upvote]

Please see above image it says I have upvoted the question, I doubt as I don't remember doing so. But just cross checked with the user's profile and checked [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1130057/gik?tab=reputation), which has nothing under his account.

So question is how does that happened ? is it bug ? or am I missing something ?

Comment: Maybe you meant to downvote and misclicked. Happens to all of us.

Comment: I really don't know what happened but really I feel somewhat ashamed, so posted question to clerify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working as designed. You certainly upvoted that answer.

The reason you don't see any reputation on the user profile is because the post is deleted; votes on deleted posts are not counted, as if the votes were never cast at all<sup>*</sup>.

From the [deletion FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that):

> - Reputation changes from votes (both up and down) on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified.

*<sub>Unless the post was at least 60 days old and had a score of 3 or higher when deleted.</sub>